# Solaris 10 Bash redirect output to a file in wrong order

Tags: bash, maven, jenkins, output, solaris

i execute command :

`groovy -cp SCRIPTS_DIR SCRIPTS_DIR/build.groovy >>output.txt 2>>error.txt`

**build.groovy** file contains svn command and lot of mvn commands. During execution file **output.txt** is changing order and some rows are added in middle of output not at the end.

Example of output.txt:

```
Executing: svn export --revision 108 --force https://svn.server.eu:/svn/TEST/trunk 101
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src/scripts
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src/template
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src/template/tools
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN/src
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN/src/main
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN/src/main/assembly
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/common
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/common/py
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/PLAIN
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/PLAIN/scripts
```

After few secunds when mvn commands are executed some of logs are between of rows related to svn export command:

```
Executing: svn export --revision 108 --force https://svn.server.eu:/svn/TEST/trunk 101
********************************************************************************
*** Check if root POM exists ***************************************************
********************************************************************************
*** Timestamp....................................: 30.03.2022 14:57:53
*** In minute since build start..................: 1
*** Root POM exists: MVN/pom.xml
********************************************************************************
*** Creating source.zip on Software Archive ************************************
********************************************************************************
*** Timestamp....................................: 30.03.2022 14:57:53
*** In minute since build start..................: 1
      [zip] Building zip: /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/source101.zip
********************************************************************************
*** Running resolve-props and lock-snapshots ***********************************
********************************************************************************
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src/scripts
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src/template
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/src/template/tools
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN/src
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN/src/main
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/MVN/src/main/assembly
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/common
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/common/py
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/PLAIN
A    /opt/eu/building/jenkins/workspace/test/101/PLAIN/scripts
```

I execute this command on different linux systems and there output.txt is correct. Only on Solaris 10 i have this 'strange' behavior of stdout. Maybe it's related to output buffering but i'm not sure.
Any solution for this ?

Comment: Bash simply appends to the file you selected; if Solaris does something weird, it's probably an OS bug.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two separate instances of this running at the same time and appending to the same file at the same time, though?

Comment: @tripleee i'm sure. Only with Solaris 10 this problem exists.

Comment: _"logs are between of rows related to svn export command"_ From what I see they are __before__; it could just be a kind of header